# Erro ao imprimir dados do mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde!
Estou listando alguns dados do mysql usando php; porém ao ser exibido no lugar das palavras que estão acentuadas eu vejo caracteres como estes **� � � �** .
Meu schema e table estão configurados com **charset** ***utf8_general_ci***.
E em meu documento html onde está sendo exibido os dados retornados do banco, possui a meta tag **charset** configurada para ***utf-8***.

Este é o código da função onde imprimo o resultado da consulta:

```
public function showTinyNews() {
    include_once 'sys/models/Connection.class.php';
    $conn = new Connection();
    $execQuery = mysqli_query($conn->connect(), "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC");

    foreach ($execQuery as $news) {
        echo "<li>
                <h2><a href='index.php?p=news&id={$news['idnews']}'>{$news['title']}</a>
                    <span>Por: {$news['author']} ({$news['date']})</span></h2>
                <p>{$news['news']}</p>
                    <a class='leia-mais' a href='index.php?p=news&id={$news['idnews']}'>leia mais</a>
            </li>";
    }
}
```

Código do Connection

```
class Connection {
static $host = 'localhost';
static $user = 'root';
static $password = '00';
static $database = 'database';

public function connect(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$host, self::$user, self::$password, self::$database);

    if(mysqli_errno($mysqli)){
        echo "Failed to connect to database: mysqli_connect_errno() 
              mysqli_connect_error()";
    } else {
        return $mysqli;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: tente usar `$conn->exec("SET CHARSET UTF-8");` ou `$conn->set_charset("utf8")`e também salve seu documento `SEM BOM`

Comment: Salvei todos os documentos relacionados como utf-8 sem bom e o erro persistiu. Porém o $conn->exec("SET CHARSET UTF-8" e $conn->set_charset("utf8") apenas geraram erro na página, na verdade apenas não exibiu as divs. e não gerou erro algum.
Alterei a pergunta com a classe Connection.

Comment: Você se certificou que os dados estão realmente em UTF-8 no DB? A melhor maneira é olhar os dados em hexadecimal, para se certificar. Não dá pra confiar na saída na tela.

Comment: Só pra constar a principio todo o db está em utf8_general_ci.

Comment: @JahnKrauss e os dados armazenados nele?

Comment: @Bacco Boa pergunta!
Com sua pergunta entendi o porque estava gerando o erro.
Quando inseri os dados fiz por um select simples e não defini isso.

Comment: @JahnKrauss a melhor certeza que você tem de uma informação no DB é olhar ela byte a byte. Geralmente os utilitários como MySQL Query Browser ou MySQL Workbench tem um modo de visualização em hexadecimal, que é um ótimo modo de se conferir os dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não acredito que seja uma duplicata. O problema não era a codificação do arquivo e sim dos dados inseridos no banco de dados.

Comment: Exemplo: `AÇÃO` em UTF-8: `0x41 0xC3 0x87 0xC3 0x83 0x4F` ...  `AÇÃO` em ISO-8859-1: `0x41 0xc7 0xc3 0x4f`

Comment: Entenda que muitas perguntas são duplicadas não por causa das perguntas, mas por que existe uma resposta em outro lugar que resolve o problema. Sendo o que no caso a resposta lá já responde ao problema proposto aqui. Duplicar perguntas não é algo prejudicial é apenas para uma pergunta levar a outra aonde tem outras possiveis solucões, note que a resposta aqui pode lhe ajudar, mas este problema pode ser ocasionado por uma série de fatores e lá existe uma resposta que abrange todos estes fatores ;)

Comment: Mais um detalhe, fechar perguntas não tem haver com votos negativos ou deletar ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e se caso eu não encontrar a solução lá, devo iniciar uma nova pergunta ou perguntar na mesma pergunta?

Comment: Sim nova pergunta mas deve justificar, acredito que lá eu tenha enumerado todos os problemas com ANSI, utf8 sem bom, mysql api e mysql engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode tentar substituir isso

```
} else {
    return $mysqli;
}
```

por isso

```
} else {
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    return $mysqli;
}
```

outra coisa

Verifique a codificação de TODOS os seus arquivos. Só a meta tag charset não é suficiente para definir a codificação para UTF-8. Você deve **salvar** os arquivos com a referida codificação. De preferencia, UTF-8 sem BOM.

Comment: De curiosidade, se eu salvar meu PHP como ISO-8859-1 no meu editor de código, em que é que isso interfere na saida do MySQL? Nao entendi direito essa parte da sua resposta.

Comment: Eu verifiquei todos os arquivos e salvei como UTF-8 sem BOM.

Comment: Na saída do MySQL realmente não interfere em nada. Mas na hora que o servidor for renderizar a página, ele vai encontrar um conflito de codificação, e vai tentar escrever UTF-8 onde só aceita ISO-8859-1. E ai sai aqueles caracteres estranhos.

Comment: @RafaelGonçalves não me fez muito sentido a  parte da renderização da página que você disse, mas era mais para ter uma idéia se o que você disse era realmente o que você quis dizer. Grato pelo retorno.

Comment: Talvez você possa me explicar melhor o que você quis dizer. Eu entendo desta forma, porém você possa ter uma explicação melhor do que a minha. Não tenho muita didática. Abraços!

Comment: @RafaelGonçalves é que nos comments ficaria meio longo. Em teoria, o encoding da página é determinado pelo `header` e/ou pela `meta` tag, e o conteúdo desta só interferiria na ausência de ambos. Mesmo assim, isso seria do lado do cliente, e não renderizado pelo server. Achei que ficou meio confuso na resposta por isso, por isso quis entender melhor sua afirmação. De qq forma, foge um pouco da pergunta original, então nao daria pra tratar disso com muita complexidade.